# Reading a grid from a file to a specific class in Java

Tags: java, file-io

*Hi guys*
I want the way how I can read the file-the link of it is in the end of qustion- and then write it to this 2D array :

```
public class Grid {
    private Square[][] sq = new Square[10][10];
}
```

the class in which it is contained like this :

```
public class Square {

    private int currentState;
    private int row;
    private char col;

    public Square() {
        super();
    }

    public Square(int currentState, int row, char col) {
        super();
        this.currentState = currentState;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

}
```

the 'currentState' variable refer to one of those :

if it's equal to 1 then the symbol is '.'
if it's equal to 2 then the symbol is '#'
if it's equal to 3 then the symbol is '*'

and 'row' variable is refer to the order of row *from 1 to 10*
and 'col' variable is refer to the order of column *from A to J*

the file that I want to read:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uEk9zRcLMO-s5efOPWS5jlRyqsLzcv-M

Hope I will find the answer

Comment: What is it you're stuck on? Or what is going different than expected? (any errors/exceptions? Did google stop working? )

Comment: I tried a lot to code it with a different java IO streams and still facing a problem when I want to print the array 'sq' it doesn't print any thing on the console , As for google it's still working and if you don't have answer be relaxed and let the others do

Comment: Than please show us the parts where you read/populate/print the array, so we can help looking for the problem.

Comment: @n247s I posted the whole code bellow , hope you can find the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should read from file using `FileInputStream` `.read()` method converting returning type from `int` to `char` until the end of file is reached. 
Process each received character and set corresponding `Square` in your array.

```
try {
    File file = new File("draft.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    char current;
    while (fis.available() > 0) {
        current = (char) fis.read();
        //process your character
    }
 } catch (IOException exc) {
 //handle the exception
 }
```

Comment: I still have a problem even when I used your code the program prints nothing when I want to print 'sq' array , I posted the whole code bellow , hope you can see it and find the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public void intilizeGrid() {
        try {
            File file = new File("draft.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            char current;
            int i = 0 , k = 0;   //from 1 to 10
            char j = 'A';    //from A to J
            while (fis.available() > 0) {
                current = (char) fis.read(); // we have to transform this to int
                while(i < maxLimit) {
                    for(k = 0;k < maxLimit;k++) {
                        sq[i][k] = new Square(determineState(current) ,i , j);
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }   
            }
         } catch (IOException exc) {
             System.out.println("Error , IO exception has been caught !!\n");
         }
    }
```

such that :

```
public int determineState(char currState) {
        switch (currState) {
        case '.':
            return 1;
        case '#':
            return 2;
        case '*':
            return 3;
        case 'u':
            return 4;
        }
        return 0;
    }

public void showGrid() {
        for(int i = 0;i < maxLimit;i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0;j < maxLimit;j++) {
                int currState = sq[i][j].getCurrentState();
                sq[i][j].showSquare(currState);
            }
        }
    }

public void showSquare(int currState) {
        char res = '\0';
        switch(currState) {
        case 1:
            res = '.';
            break;
        case 2:
            res = '#';
            break;
        case 3:
            res = '*';
            break;
        case 4:
            res = 'u';
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("    " + res + "    ");
    }
```

And in the main I have :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.intilizeGrid();
        g.showGrid();
    }
}
```

And it prints nothing on the console so what's wrong ???

Comment: in the `InitializeGrid` you are setting the whole grid to a read char (not just one place per char). so the array is set to the last char. What I suspect is that because you use the `available` method the last char is the `EOF` char. Meaning it cannot be converted to a state (so `\0` is returned), which get set to the whole array. if you would only change the loop so it would populate one char per read, things will become vissible. If you really wanna fix things, check the returned value of `read`.

Comment: Here is an [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_read.htm) where you can read on how to use `FileInputStream#read` in a correct way.

Comment: I tried as you said but seems the logic of code is wrong I tried to fix it but gives me 'nullPointerException' and I don't know how to fix it , the edited code is posted bellow check it out please

Comment: You can edit your own question / answer, it makes it less messy. Anyways, if you have a NPE you can google a guide how to fix it, otherwise post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

```
//maxLimit = 10
public void intilizeGrid() {

             String draftFile = "draft.txt";
             FileInputStream draft = null;

            try {   
                draft = new FileInputStream(draftFile);     
                int temp;
                char current = '\0';
                int i = 0, j = 0;
                char k = 'A';
                while ((temp = draft.read()) != -1) {
                    if(current != ' ') {
                        if (j == maxLimit) {
                            j = 0; i++; k = 'A';
                        }
                        if (i == maxLimit)
                            break;
                        current = (char) temp;
                        sq[i][j] = new Square(determineState(current), i, k);
                        j++; k++;
                    }

                }
             } catch (IOException exc) {
                 System.out.println("Error , IO exception has been caught !!\n");
             }
        }
```